# Can someone explain the output of this c++ program?

Tags: c++, rvo, nrvo

Why is the output **`foo3`** equal to **`3`** ?
i would suggest, when `bar(foo1)` is called, the function `bar` creates a copy of `foo1` on the stack, so it's value is equal to 0, when this value is returned, the copy-constructor for `foo3` increments the value again so it should be 2?

Thanks in advance.

this is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
struct Foo {
    Foo()
        : x(0)
    {
    }
    Foo(const Foo& foo)
        : x(foo.x + 1)
    {
    }
    int x;
};

Foo bar(Foo foo)
{
    foo.x++;
    return foo;
}

int main()
{
    Foo foo1;
    Foo foo2 = foo1;
    std::cout << "A:" << foo1.x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "B:" << foo2.x << std::endl;
    Foo foo3 = bar(foo1);
    std::cout << "C:" << foo3.x << std::endl;
}
```

output:

```
A:0
B:1
C:3
```

Comment: Read about [RVO and NRVO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization).

Comment: Perhaps using a debugger and putting a break point in the copy constructor would help.

Comment: A `bar` definition like this `Foo bar(Foo& foo)`, would have produced the output `C:2`

Comment: @AlokSave NRVO / RVO does not apply when the variable is the function argument. If bar was: `Foo bar(Foo const& foo){ Foo foo2(foo);  foo2.x ++ ;  return foo2; }`  then the compiler would be allowed to do copy elision, In that case a modern compiler would probably give: `A:0 B:1 C:2`

Comment: Please mark one of these answers as accepted if they have answered your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there are three copy constructors at work here, the line `foo2 = foo1`, the passing of `foo1` into `bar`, and the returning of `foo1` from `bar`.

Modifying your code makes it clear what is happening:

```
#include <iostream>
struct Foo {
    Foo()
        : x(0)
    {
        std::cout << "Constructor called" << std::endl;
    }
    Foo(const Foo& foo)
        : x(foo.x + 1)
    {
        std::cout << "Copy constructor called" << std::endl;
    }
    int x;
};

Foo bar(Foo foo)
{
    std::cout << "B2:" << foo.x << std::endl;
    foo.x++;
    return foo;
}

int main()
{
    Foo foo1;
    Foo foo2 = foo1;
    std::cout << "A:" << foo1.x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "B:" << foo2.x << std::endl;
    Foo foo3 = bar(foo1);
    std::cout << "C:" << foo3.x << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Constructor called
Copy constructor called
A:0
B:1
Copy constructor called
B2:1
Copy constructor called
C:3
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create the first `foo1`, its `x` is zero. The call to `bar` passes by value, so it is copied - so the param in `bar` has a value of 1. The function `bar` itself increments `x` further by 1, so it is now 2. Finally, the return statement once again returns by value, so there is another copy - thus the final `x` is 3.

Note RVO does not apply here, because `Foo` is not returning a local variable by value - rather it is returning a parameter, which must actually be copied.

From the standard [class.copy/31], circumstances under which copy elision is permitted, which specifically exclude cases where function parameters are returned:

> — in a return statement in a function with a class return type, when
>   the expression is the name of a non-volatile automatic object (**other
>   than a function or catch-clause parameter**) with the same cv-unqualified
>   type as the function return type, the copy/move operation can be
>   omitted by constructing the automatic object directly into the
>   function’s return value

Comment: What's the difference between a (by-value) parameter and a local variable with regards to RVO?

Comment: @sepp2k: The calling convention dictates where parameters and return values must be placed, there's no flexibility to make those overlap.  It doesn't dictate where a temporary (RVO) or local variable (NRVO) is placed, giving the compiler the flexibility to place it directly in the return value location.

Comment: @BenVoigt That makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: @sepp2k - as per above edit standard specifically forbids copy elision when returning a function parameter.

Answer (score 0):

- `0 -> 1` You copy `foo1` to the parameter of `bar`.
- `1 -> 2` You increment `x` within `bar`.
- `2 -> 3` You copy `bar` to the temporary return value.

I count three increments.

Answer (score 0):

When doing:

```
Foo foo2 = foo1;
```

you are calling the copy ctor, so foo2.x's value will be 1.
Then when calling:

```
Foo foo3 = bar(foo1);
```

because you are not passing by reference the argument of 'bar' is created a copy of foo1 into bar using the copy ctor (x == 1). After that that copy's x member is incremented(x == 2) and at last is returned. When returning is not created an other copy because 'return value optimization'(still x == 2).
Finally foo3 is initialized using again the copy ctor(x == 3).